# Second wheel set for winter

Tags: wheels

I commute every day on my trekking bike and when it is snowy/icy, I replace my normal tires with some studded tires.

The studded tires are ace, but replacing the tires is a real pain in the ass.

So I'm thinking of buying a replacement set of wheels to fit the winter tires onto.

What do I have to consider when buying new wheels?

Comment: Cost, for one. How long do you reckon you'd need them, in terms of weeks per year? I'd suggest that you spend in proportion to your needs. Or alternatively, get some nice new wheels and put them away until the good weather, and start thinking of your current wheels as your "winter" wheels. Again, depends how much you want to spend.

Comment: Yeah, all you really want is wheels the right size.  Forget about fancy bladed spokes, et al.

Comment: Also same cassette size

Comment: Is it possible to buy wheels with cassette already fitted? Would I need a new chain to fit the new cassette?

Comment: how often do you switch to studded tires? I switch only once per year, and keep them on till spring.

Comment: if your now wheel has a new cassette, than it would be good that chain is also new when you put the wheel on.

Comment: any bike store will fit a cassette to the wheel. If you want to diy you just need a locking tool e.g. [this one for Shimano](http://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-fr-1) and a wrench

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also considered doing this.

Firstly what type of brakes you have will depend on what you need.

You need to look for

- size. Most important get the same as you have already. Also check the rim width with rim brakes as mentioned in comments below
- weight -if you have money to spend get some quality lightweight ones. If they are better than your existing ones, consider these you new summer ones and use the old ones for winter
- brakes (disc or rim) If you have disc brakes you will need rotors too, or you'll be swapping them out all the time too.
- cassette. You'll need a wheelset which can accommodate a cassette that matches the the current one on your bike. There's no need to replace the chain if you are getting the same speed (number of cogs) cassette. Genreal consensus in the comments below is also to replace/swap the chain.

Also cleaning the chainset will help a great deal in looking after your bike for the winter

So in summary you will need a new cassette and new disc rotors if you have disc brakes to save you swapping these out all the time.

How often do you change the tyres? is it worth the cost if you change them 4 times a year?

Comment: As to the cassette: You do not only have to consider the number of cogs, but also the wear level. If you install a new cassette on your winter wheelset and have a cassette with some thousand kms on your summer wheelset, the chain will likely slip.

Comment: Also, depending on what winter is like in your area, the salt will destroy your chain anyway, so it's best to get a chain that's cheap and you don't mind having destroyed for the winter.  I actually have a completely separate bike for late fall/early spring (winter isn't worth riding in my area) so that I don't total my good bike.

Comment: Also also, make sure when using rim brakes that you're purchasing wheels with the same rim width so that you don't have to totally readjust your brakes when you swap (or in some cases, wind up with a rim that is physically too wide for your frame.)

Comment: One could, of course, swap a single cassette between wheels.  But that's probably a bad idea, as the risk of cross-threading would increase with frequent swaps.  The cassette should be the same number of cogs, of course, but can have a slightly different tooth count if desired -- but hopefully not enough different to require changing chain length.

Comment: Re the chain, probably simplest to use the "summer" chain through winter and then replace it when swapping wheels the last time in the spring.

Comment: Thanks for all the great advice. I have V-Brakes, and there is loads of salt on the roads at the moment (North-East Germany) so I guess my bike is getting damaged. But it's not an expensive bike.

Comment: I ride about 3000km a year - and only really need the winter setup for a few weeks.

Comment: If there's lots of salt. be sure to clean and lubricate your chain, cassette, etc and hubs frequently. After every ride is best. Spray a good water dispersant on there such as GT85 after cleaning